# Checking if the array in foreach loop is empty or not

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to check if my array is empty or not but strangely I can't get it working.

```
foreach ($friend as $key => $id){

    $friendActivity = $db->friendActivity($id);

    if (!empty($friendActivity)) {

        //rest of the code

    }

}
```

I have used **var_dump($friendActivity)** before the ***if statement*** and the result is as follow:

```
array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

//////---> Something to know <--------/////////

I am not trying to see the count of arrays. Each user in database has some activities. I want to see if those activities match with the (poll of of activities). So if the user has mentioned about their activities, therefore the $friendActivity is not going to be empty.

If I use empty:

```
if (empty($friendActivity)){

    //rest of the code

}
```

I am able to get inside the if condition...

I personally think, that I have to delete the array at the end of each foreach loop, so that I don't store the other user's friends activities.

Comment: Event when its empty you are getting inside the if? btw: there are some changes on the results empty() shows since php 5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: yes, I have re edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

`count()` should give you an accurate array number: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

```
if (count($friendActivity) > 0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have re-edited the question, I am not trying to count the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
if (sizeof($friendActivity) > 0) {
```